# Android: Placing cursor information into an object

Tags: android, user-interface, cursor

Is there a way to complete cursor queries **off the main thread** that update specific fields in a List of objects?  I have looked into CursorAdapter examples from the Google Development Library, however, most solutions simply update ListView rows with the queried information, not pre-existing objects.

Is my only solution to query the information in an implementation specific thread, or is there something similar to CursorAdapter for the process I am describing.  Thanks in advance! All links appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple in Android by using Loader. Please refer
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html
Loader is ideal for this. If you find any issues for implementing this, tell me. I can help you with some samples

Comment: This looks promising... before I dive in, do I query everything I need and then in onLoadFinished use the Cursor to iterate through the data and instantiate my List of objects?

Comment: Yes Cursor is used for data. Typically you can use the CursorLoader class. This Loader performs query in the background thread.
The CursorLoader replaced deprecated Activity-managed cursors.
If the Cursor becomes invalid, the onLoaderReset() method can be called.